# getting error while converting ppt file to PDF in java

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm just beginner in java

I trying to convert PPT file to PDF file using **apache poi** and **Itext** library but i'm getting error of **NoSuchMethodError**

*I tried all the version of Apache poi and poi-ooxml but i'm getting same error 
please help me to findout Solution for this error*

### Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
public class PPTtoPDF {

    public PPTtoPDF() {

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void convertPPTToPDF(String sourcepath, String destinationPath) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcepath);
        double zoom = 2;
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);
        Document pdfDocument = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(destinationPath));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        pdfWriter.open();
        pdfDocument.open();
        Dimension pgsize = null;
        Image slideImage = null;
        BufferedImage img = null;

            SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
            pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
            Slide slide[] = ppt.getSlides();
            System.out.println("Length----> "+slide.length);
            pdfDocument.setPageSize(new Rectangle((float) pgsize.getWidth(), (float) pgsize.getHeight()));
            pdfWriter.open();
            pdfDocument.open();
            for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
                img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(pgsize.width * zoom), (int) Math.ceil(pgsize.height * zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
                graphics.setTransform(at);

                graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
                graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
                slide[i].draw(graphics);
                graphics.getPaint();
                slideImage = Image.getInstance(img, null);
                table.addCell(new PdfPCell(slideImage, true));
                System.out.println(table);
            }

        pdfDocument.add(table);
        pdfDocument.close();
        pdfWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Powerpoint file converted to PDF successfully");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        PPTtoPDF pp = new PPTtoPDF();
        pp.convertPPTToPDF("D:\\tp\\slides.ppt", "D:\\tp\\1.pdf");
    }
}
```

and the error is

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument.<init>(Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem;)V
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow.<init>(HSLFSlideShow.java:134)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow.<init>(HSLFSlideShow.java:120)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow.<init>(HSLFSlideShow.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow.<init>(SlideShow.java:122)
    at convertService.PPTtoPDF.convertPPTToPDF(PPTtoPDF.java:44)
    at convertService.PPTtoPDF.main(PPTtoPDF.java:75)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Apache POI FAQ entry on this very topic.](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)  What has almost certainly happened is that you have added a new copy of POI to your classpath, but an older version was already there (from an earlier need, your framework etc), and Java is now getting confused about which one to use.

You could use tool for that:

- mvn dependency
- tree JDK 8: jdeps

(https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool)

> jdeps is a new command-line tool added since JDK 8 for developers to
>   use to understand the static dependencies of their applications and
>   libraries. jdeps is a static analysis tool on the given class files

Comment: i check POI version using this code it takes proper file for execution but still giving same error 
  
 ClassLoader classloader =org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path);